# Align a word to a point past the right margin

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment

I made a simple title command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{graphics}

\newcommand{\modtitle}[2]{%
    \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}\noindent\hspace*{-.75in}%
    \resizebox{\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}\\%
    \hspace*{.1in}{\large \textsc{ \ \hfill \hspace*{.625in} #2}}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
}

\begin{document}
    \modtitle{This is the Title}{The Author}

\end{document}
```

But the author space is lined up with the right margin, not `0.625in` further to the right where it belongs. Obviously my `\hspace*{.625in}` command is being swallowed by the `\hfill`. How could I push it over a little?

Comment: So the left overhang for the main title should be/is `.75in` and the right overhang for the main title should be/is `.5in` (totalling `1.25in+\linewidth`). Then, you want the author to start `0.625in` after the right margin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a stack.  The current (default) gap is `3pt`, but you can alter that with `\stackunder[8pt]{...}` or some other suitable dimension.

I left the top line horizontally positioned where the OP had it (which is not centered).  If one wants it centered, the follow-up coding below will achieve that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{graphics,stackengine}

\def\mmodtitle#1#2{\def\stackalignment{r}%
    \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}\noindent\hspace*{-.75in}%
    \stackunder{%
    \resizebox{\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}%
    }{%
    {\large\textsc{#2}}%
    }
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
}
\begin{document}
    \mmodtitle{This is the Title}{The Author}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if you want the header centered, here is how the macro might be modified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{graphics,stackengine}

\def\modtitle#1#2{\def\stackalignment{r}%
    \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{%
    \stackunder{%
    \resizebox{\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}%
    }{%
    {\large\textsc{#2}}%
    }}%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
}
\begin{document}
    \modtitle{This is the Title}{The Author}

\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `\hspace*{.1in}`? Also, how do we know that the box is centred? I'm not following the dimensions used

Comment: @Sigur Sorry, that was detritus from the OP's question.  Removed.

Comment: Thanks. But how to know that it is on the centre? What is the relation between `-.75in` and `\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth`? What is going on behind the curtains?

Comment: @Sigur That part I carried through from the OP's query, assuming that he got the top line where he wanted it.  His problem was with the underset, so I didn't tamper with the first part.  If I fully digest what it does, I'll let you know.  In fact, it is not centered, as a following `\noindent\hrulefill` will attest.  So it would appear to hang out .75in to the left and .5 in to the right of the margin.

Comment: I compared your code with cfr's code using both `\mmodtitle{This is the Title}{Steven}\\ \vspace{.5in} \modtitle{This is the Title}{cfr}` and then we can see the difference. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Sigur I have added a follow-up to show how I would center the header horizontally, *if* that is what the OP desired.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I really like the stack syntax, it's really intuitive. Why did you switch to `\def\modtitle#1#2{` syntax instead of the `\newcommand{}` syntax?

Comment: @Ryan Purely laziness of not wanting to type the extra letters of `newcommand`.  Best to change it back.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\modtitle}[2]{%
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
    \resizebox{\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}\\
    \large \textsc{#2}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
    \modtitle{This is the Title}{The Author}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}` with no `\multicolumn`?

Comment: @egreg Certainly! Thank you. Corrected now. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way. Note that I've centred the title (I think) relative to the body of text which I took to be your intent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics,calc}

\newsavebox{\modtitlebox}
\newcommand{\modtitle}[2]{%
  \sbox{\modtitlebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr1.25in+\textwidth}
        \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}%
        {\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}\par}
        \hspace*{\fill}\large\textsc{#2}\vspace{\baselineskip}\par
    \end{minipage}}%
  \centering
  \makebox[0pt]{\usebox{\modtitlebox}}}

\begin{document}
  \modtitle{This is the Title}{The Author}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified title]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you put the given space *before* #2, but you have to put the negative space *after* #2 in the `\hbox to\hsize`. (You can use `\line` instead `\hbox to\hsize` in plain TeX but you can't use this in LaTeX.)

You can think about this:

```
\newdimen\overmargin \overmargin=.625in
\def\modtitle#1#2{%
    \vglue-5\baselineskip
    \hbox{\kern-\overmargin\resizebox{\dimexpr2\overmargin+\hsize}{!}{\textsc{#1}}}
    \hbox to\hsize{\hfill #2\kern-\overmargin}
    \vskip \baselineskip
}
```

or this:

```
\newdimen\overmargin \overmargin=.625in
\def\modtitle#1#2{%
    \vglue-5\baselineskip
    \moveleft\overmargin\hbox{\resizebox{\dimexpr2\overmargin+\hsize}{!}{\textsc{#1}}}
    \moveright\overmargin\hbox to\hsize{\hfill #2}
    \vskip \baselineskip
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `\rlap`produces what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{graphics}

\newcommand{\modtitle}[2]{%
    \vspace*{-5\baselineskip}\noindent\hspace*{-.75in}%
    \resizebox{\dimexpr1.25in+\linewidth}{!}{\textsc{#1}}\\%
    \hspace*{.1in}{\large \textsc{ \ \hfill \rlap{\hspace*{.625in} #2}}}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}\\
}

\begin{document}
    \modtitle{This is the Title}{The Author}

\end{document}
```

[image]